# Linux, centos, resetting password

Tags: linux, unix, centos, passwords

While resetting password after commands:

```
rd.break 
mount -o remount,rw /sysroot 
chroot /sysroot
```

I entered new password all done correctly at the end created file reliably  using

```
touch /.autorelable
```

It still has the wrong password while entering the right password.

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem (but sorry no one from the community spotted it!).  Since the problem was a typo, and the question and its solution aren't likely to be useful to other readers in the future, I'm voting to close the question.  There's absolutely nothing wrong with it, and I'm glad you asked it!  It's just normal "clean-up".  Looking forward to more contributions from you in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the wrong was with the spelling of

> /.autorelabel